# Protobuf ld undefined symbol ~InternalMetadata()

Tags: c++, linker, embedded, protocol-buffers

I'm hitting an issue with some fairly basic Protobuf files in a library of mine. This is built as a static library successfully but then when compiling tests (Catch2) and linking to the same protobuf library I'm getting the below undefined symbol:-

```
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: /usr/local/bin/cmake --build /Volumes/TB3-1/git/skunkworks/herald-for-cpp/build --config Debug --target herald-tests --
[build] [1/1 100% :: 0.182] Linking CXX executable herald-tests/herald-tests
[build] FAILED: herald-tests/herald-tests 
[build] : && /usr/bin/clang++ -g -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  herald-tests/CMakeFiles/herald-tests.dir/test-templates.cpp.o herald-tests/CMakeFiles/herald-tests.dir/test-util.cpp.o herald-tests/CMakeFiles/herald-tests.dir/mesh-tests.cpp.o herald-tests/CMakeFiles/herald-tests.dir/main.cpp.o -o herald-tests/herald-tests  herald/libherald.a  /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.a  /usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib/libcrypto.a && :
[build] Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
[build]   "google::protobuf::internal::InternalMetadata::~InternalMetadata()", referenced from:
[build]       google::protobuf::MessageLite::~MessageLite() in libherald.a(modem.pb.cc.o)
[build]       google::protobuf::MessageLite::~MessageLite() in libherald.a(mesh.pb.cc.o)
[build]       google::protobuf::MessageLite::~MessageLite() in libherald.a(models.pb.cc.o)
[build] ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
[build] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[build] ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
[build] Build finished with exit code 1
```

The super interesting thing is it even complains about the missing symbol from the ~MessageLite call when I force SPEED instead of LITE_RUNTIME. Doesn't seem to matter whether I link the library and programme to the dylib or the static lib on my mac, whether the full library or the lite library. Tried both SPEED and LITE_RUNTIME in my proto files with exactly the same result.

I've been struggling with this a while. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Note: My library's target platform ranges from a container on a server to an embedded hardware device. These particular tests are compiled local (Mac OS X x86_64 Intel Mac in my case currently).

Comment: The error message sounds like the library linked could be of different version than the headers found during compilation. Note that the generated files have google/protobuf at the beginning of the included file name, so -I /usr/local/include might be needed.

Comment: Why don't [brew install protobuf](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/protobuf) instead of building from the sources?

Comment: I've brew install protobuf as well as building from source - same outcome. There's only a single set of headers available. I'll double check the system include folder is definitely in both CMake project include lists.

Comment: Yes, as expected the -I isn't required. We're failing at the linking stage not the compilation stage. It can find all the other protobuf symbols, just not that specific one needed by MessageLite's destructor.

Answer (score 6):

This issue [was tracked here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/9947) and ought to be fixed in the recently released Protobuf 3.21.3.

The library builds that ship with package managers are usually built with `NDEBUG` defined (`-DNDEBUG` to the compiler, `#define NDEBUG` in the code). Usually this just turns off checking `assert()` macros, but Protobuf keys on this symbol to turn on and off its own internal debugging. It turns out that in release mode the `InternalMetadata` destructor was always inlined and (with `-fvisibility-inlines-hidden` in the compiler options) never produced a symbol to link against, while in debug mode it was not always inlined and needed to be linked against.

So trying to build user code that didn't define `NDEBUG` for the Protobuf headers would result in code that needed to link against that destructor, which wouldn't be in the release Protobuf packaged libraries.

The workaround is to use `-DNDEBUG` in your application, or to build a debug build of Protobuf to link against, or to use a Protobuf new enough (3.21.3+) or old enough (I think <=3.19) to not have this particular problem.

The only remaining mystery is why the whole Internet noticed this bug in the past few days, when it's been there for much longer.

Comment: I'm using 3.20.3 and -DNDEBUG solved my problem. Thank you!